# In case of a process context switch, is the virtual address space (VAS) of the new process loaded into the CPU context (CPU's registers)?

Tags: linux, multithreading, linux-kernel, multitasking, context-switch

I have read:

> Process switching is context switching from one process to a different process. It involves switching out all of the process abstractions and resources in favor of those belonging to a new process. Most notably and expensively, this means switching the memory address space. This includes memory addresses, mappings, page tables, and kernel resources—a relatively expensive operation.

Also:

> A context is the contents of a CPU's registers and program counter at any point in time.
>
> Context switching can be described in slightly more detail as the kernel (i.e., the core of the operating system) performing the following activities with regard to processes (including threads) on the CPU: (1) suspending the progression of one process and storing the CPU's state (i.e., the context) for that process somewhere in memory, (2) retrieving the context of the next process from memory and restoring it in the CPU's registers and (3) returning to the location indicated by the program counter (i.e., returning to the line of code at which the process was interrupted) in order to resume the process.

As the **VAS** is separate for each process and can be of size up to 4GB, is the whole **VAS** of a process loaded into the CPU context in case of context switch of the process?

Also as each process has separate **page table**, is the page table also brought into the CPU context in case of a context switch ?

If no, then why is a process context switch slower than a thread context switch (threads share the same **VAS**)?

Comment: What is VAS? Set of all virtual addresses? Set of mappings from virtual addresses to physical addresses? Something else?

Comment: By VAS I meant, virtual address space of a particular process.

Comment: What *is* a virtual address space? If you have e.g. [this definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) in mind, then the phrase "VAS is separate for each process" doesn't make much sense.

Comment: By VAS I meant virtual Memory addresses for main memory(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_address). @n.m.

Comment: There are many types of memory addresses: physical, virtual, linear... Which one do you mean?

Comment: @n.m. Why doesn't it make sense? "the set of ranges of virtual addresses that an operating system makes available to a process" is pretty clearly referring to *one* process. And the comment before yours clearly says virtual.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart the linked text explains very clearly that all processes have access to the same range of virtual addresses, e.g. all 32-bit addresses for a 32-bit OS/machine.

Comment: Didn't see the comment says virtual (font on the phone is not ideal). So we have "virtual addresses for main memory". Do you mean only those virtual addresses that are backed by the main memory? The set of such addresses is by no means unique. Two processes can easily have the same set of mapped addresses. Do you need "mapping from virtual to physical addresses"? This mapping is implemented by "paging tables" which are stored in memory, not in the CPU.

Comment: While "space" may not be the best term here, I think it's obvious the OP is asking how the "virtual-to-physical memory map" is swapped for processes. What term would you instead use, to say "`WriteProcessMemory` writes into the *virtual address space* of another process"?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I'd say "writes to the memory of the target process", or "to the virtual memory" if a clarification is needed. Virtual memory is physical memory mapped to the virtual address space, i.e. it involves not just an address space but also a mapping a.k.a. paging tables.

Comment: @n.m. Terminology is always the hardest part :-)  I'll add that the Linux kernel calls this an `mm`, which I think means "memory map" or "memory management".

Answer (score 9):

> As the VAS is separate for each process and can be of size upto 4GB,is the whole VAS of a process is loaded in the CPU context in case of context switch of the process ?
>
> Also as each process has separate page table, does the page table is also bought in the CPU context in case of context switch ?

These questions are related. You swap out one virtual address space for another ***by*** changing which set of page tables is performing the virtual -> linear translation.  That's how the address space swap is accomplished.

Let's consider a very simple example.

- Say we have two processes P<sub>A</sub> and P<sub>B</sub>. Both processes are executing their program image at virtual address 0x1000.
- Not visible to the processes are a set of page tables, which map the virtual address space to physical pages of RAM:

  - Pagetable T<sub>A</sub> maps virtual address 0x1000 to physical address 0x88000
  - Pagetable T<sub>B</sub> maps virtual 0x1000 to physical 0x99000.
- Let's say the theoretical CPU has a register called `PP` (pagetable pointer)

After the processes have been initialized, "swapping the virtual address space" between the two is simple.  To load the address space for P<sub>A</sub>, you simply put the address of T<sub>A</sub> in `PP`, and now that process "sees" the memory at 0x88000. And likewise the address of T<sub>B</sub> for P<sub>B</sub>, so he will "see" the memory at 0x99000.

When switching between threads (of the same process), the virtual address space does not need changed (because all threads of a given process share the same virtual address space).

Of course there are other things which need swapped in as well (like the CPU registers), but for this discussion, we're only concerned with virtual memory.

On x86 CPUs, the `CR3` register is the pointer to the base of the page table hierarchy. It is this register which the OS changes to change address spaces when swapping processes.

---

Of course, it's more complicated than that.  Because the possible virtual address space is so large (4 GiB on x86-32, and 16 *exabytes* on x86-64), the pagetables themselves would take up a ridiculous amount of space (one entry for every 4 KiB page).  To alleviate this, additional levels of indirection are added to the pagetables, which is why I referred to them as a *hierarchy*.  On x86-64, there are 4 levels.

Now imagine if the CPU had to "walk" these paging structures for *every* virtual-to-physical translation. A single read from virtual memory would require a total of 5 memory accesses! This would be terribly slow.

Enter the [Translation lookaside buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_lookaside_buffer), or TLB. The TLB *caches* these translations, so a given virtual-to-physical translation only requires the pagetables to be walked once. After that, the TLB remembers the translation, and is much faster. (Of course the TLB can get full, but cache eviction is another story).

So say P<sub>A</sub> is running, and all of a sudden the kernel swaps in the address space for P<sub>B</sub>. Now all of those cached virtual-to-physical translations are no longer valid for the new virtual address space! That means we need to *flush* the TLB, or clear all of its entries out. And because of that, the CPU has to do the slow pagetable walking again, until the TLB cache "heats up" again.

*This* is why it's considered "expensive" to swap virtual address spaces. Not because it's hard to write to `CR3`, but because we trash the TLB every time we do.

Comment: Oh, so in case of context switch of process, the only page table is bought is the CPU context, as the VAS is same for all the processes ? But isn't loading pagetable in context is expensive ?

Comment: No. Every process has it's own virtual address space.

Comment: See updated answer, explaining why VA swaps are expensive.